# Assign default value to cell in Excel dropdown and should accept any other value

Tags: excel, vba, automated-tests

I am using Excel sheet as test data source for my automation scripts and I want to reduce test data creation time by selecting default values for cell.
Query:

I have column as Company name so by default I want to auto populate value as "XYZ" for all cells which are null.

Tried two options:

1. Data validation list: I have inserted list with my default value as XYZ however if I want to add some other value I have to go back and edit the list. Want to avoid this manual effort.W ith auto-population it should allow user to enter any value.
2. Added formula: `=IF(A2="","XYZ")`
   A (Company ID in Excel). It shows an error-Try moving your formula to different cell

Could anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: It is not clear where your formula ends. Please format it.

Comment: If A1 has data (or is empty) use the following formula in B2: `=IF(A2="","XYZ",A2)`. Which means if A2 is empty default B2 to `XYZ` otherwise use the value of A2 in B2.